# Why can't I chat anywhere even though I am not suspended on software engineering?

Tags: support, suspensions

[image]

Why can't I chat anywhere even though I am not suspended? What is the "Parent site?" The parent user is not suspended. Can someone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are suspended on a number of sites on the network, such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9796889/asadefa), [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/1138363/asadefa), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/146707/asadefa), and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/380893/asadefa). My initial guess is that your chat user was initially associated with one of these accounts when you were suspended and that applied the suspension to your chat account. However, I'm not intimately familiar with how chat suspensions are affected by main site suspensions. I'm not sure if reparenting your chat user will clear the suspension after some time or if you need to wait until one or more of those site suspensions are lifted.